# Can I freeze hot soup?

Tags: freezing, soup

Can I put hot soup  straight  in to the freezer or should I let it cool?  With my old frig I used to divide it into meal size portions and seal in freezer bags inside tupper ware containers.  Now I have a new frig I am wondering whether this would upset the automatic functions.

Comment: related http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/16540/freeze-soup-very-quickly-without-destroying-the-content-in-fridge

Answer (score 7):

It is better to let it cool down a little, because the hot items put into the refrigerator can raise the temperature inside.

If your refrigerator gets warm, it can cause harmful bacteria to grow on your food.

This can result in food poisoning, and the damage of the dairy products mainly (then you will have to get rid of them). It's better to be safe and wait for the food to cool first.

To cool them quickly, you can place them in a cold bath containing some ice cubes.